# adb in console not working but eclipse DDMS works fine

Tags: android, adb, logcat

In eclipse the DDMS View shows both, my device AND the emulator.

When i type adb devices in the console, it kills the adb server, then restarts it and only shows me the emulator.

It does not make a difference if i start the console as user or admin.

I would like to be able to use adb in the console.

Anybody out there having the same issue and solved it?

Comment: I have the same issue with Nexus One of mine, but have not solved it (haven not tried hard though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**adb** is in android-sdk-location\ *platform-tools*
**ddms** is in android-sdk-location\ *tools*.
You must set visibility of this directories on your $PATH.
Is possible you have more than one adb
and when you start it from console,
it is executed from another path ... and from there your problem.

Verify "echo $PATH$" in your console.
Verify in $PATH there are "platform-tools" and "tools" also.
Verify if there is more than one adb on directories declared on your $PATH.

I hope this help you.

Comment: hmm i didnt have platform tools in my PATH but i could still call adb from anywhere... oh shizzl now i see there is an adb.exe in my c:Windows folder, hum? i guess kies installed it there? thank you that solved it!!!